# superscript in my reference--bibtex

Tags: bibtex, subscripts, superscripts

I'm using bibtex to edit my references. My code is as follow:

```
@article{goldbeter1990,
    author = "A and B",
    title = "Model for signal-induced Ca2+ and IP3 oscillations",
    journal = "ABC",
    volume = "87",
    pages = "1-11",
    year = "1990",
}
```

In the "title" section, I would like to make the "2+" as superscript and "3" as subscript.

How could I get it?

Answer (score 14):

Normal subscript `$_{}$` and superscripts `$^{}$` commands can be used in fields in bibtex.

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{paper.bib}
@article{goldbeter1990,
    author = "A and B",
    title = "Model for signal-induced {Ca$^{2+}$} and {IP$_3$} oscillations",
    journal = "ABC",
    volume = "87",
    pages = "1-11",
    year = "1990",
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document} 
A non-linear model of the gap junctional mechanisms was developed to demonstrate 
long-range propagation of intercellular Ca$^{2+}$ waves in networks of astrocytes 
\cite{goldbeter1990}. 

\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{paper} 
\end{document}
```

produces with the correct superscript and subscripts.

[image]